# Carbon-emacs: re-enable hash key?

Tags: macos, emacs, carbon-emacs

How can I re-enable the hash (#) key in carbon-emacs on the mac? I've tried everything I've come across in google and still can't get it working.

My config file currently looks like this:

```
(require 'redo+)
(require 'mac-key-mode)
(mac-key-mode 1)
(setq default-input-method "MacOSX")
(setq mac-command-modifier 'alt mac-option-modifier 'meta)
```

The above has enabled all the Command+Key bindings (such as Cmd+S for saving), but Alt+3 isn't working.

I'd normally work around it but I'm programming in Python and # is rather useful for comments! ;)

Comment: There are keyboard layouts which doesn't require Option to generate hash -- US QWERTY and Dvorak, for example, have it as Shift-3.  Is this too intrusive?

Comment: You could also always just bind (insert "#") to M-3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emacs question - hash key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977069/emacs-question-hash-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about adding this to .emacs, setting up a macro and then binding M-3 to it:

```
(fset 'insertPound
   "#")
(global-set-key (kbd "M-3") 'insertPound)
```

Comment: it's good, but it doesn't work when doing isearch (It stops the search and puts the '#' into the main buffer, instead.)

Comment: to follow up on my own comment, (define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-3") '(lambda () (interactive) (isearch-process-search-char ?\#)))

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late and the answer has been accepted. However, I have just moved from Linux to MacOS and had the same problem.

Posted my response on a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21722619/1308653

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Have you thought about moving to [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/)?

Comment: Well, it's still emacs under the hood, and its emacs which is seeing Alt+3 as M-3 and doing nothing about it.

Comment: The stuff "under the hood" is not what gets key events from the OS.